# Doesn't "\romannumeral1986" equal "mcmlxxxvi" in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, roman-numerals, uppercase, expandafter

In TeX,

```
\uppercase{\romannumeral1986}\par
%\catcode`\m=12
\uppercase{mcmlxxxvi}
\bye
```

produces

[image]

So, doesn't `mcmlxxxvi` equal `\romannumeral1986`? What the difference between them? `\expandafter` can bypass this problem. `\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral1986}` will produce `MCMLXXXVI`. What is the reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The primitive `\uppercase` doesn't expand its arguments. What it does is take every character token in the range `a-z` and replace them by their upper case counterparts.  So when you issue

`\uppercase{\romannumeral1986}`

you are making `\uppercase` act on a group of tokens, the first of which is a primitive `\romannumeral`, followed by `1`, and `9`, and `8`, and `6`. None of these being one of the 26 characters that `\uppercase` cares about, it does nothing. And so the output is exactly `\romannumeral1986`.

As you saw, if you use `\expandafter` to expand the argument first, you get the desired effect.

---

As an aside, it is very fun to watch the expansion process in action using the [unravel package](https://ctan.org/pkg/unravel), probably seeing it in action will make it easier to follow the design of TeX.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149885/discussion-on-answer-by-willie-wong-doesnt-romannumeral1986-equal-mcmlxxxvi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 9):

No reader is supposed to know all of what follows when reading chapter 7 for the first time and, indeed, exercise 7.9 is marked as doubly dangerous.

The dangerous bend marks are very important: during a first reading, dangerous bends should be skipped; on a second reading, one can look at them and skip the doubly dangerous ones. On a third (or fourth) reading, one is expected to be able to confront with doubly dangerous parts.

Don't feel bad if you don't understand dangerous paragraphs at the beginning: you're supposed not to.

---

And now for something completely different: let's explain what happens, with a knowledge of the TeXbook from Preface to Appendix J.

The primitives `\uppercase` and `\lowercase` are pretty unique in their behavior. First off, let's see their syntax:

`\uppercase`⟨general text⟩
`\lowercase`⟨general text⟩

⟨general text⟩ → ⟨filler⟩`{`⟨balanced text⟩⟨right brace⟩
⟨filler⟩ → ⟨optional spaces⟩ | ⟨filler⟩`\relax`⟨optional spaces⟩

Finally, a ⟨balanced text⟩ is any sequence of tokens which is balanced with respect to *explicit* `{` and `}`.

What makes the two primitives with respect to others that expect a ⟨general text⟩ is that the ⟨balanced text⟩ is directly sent to the “stomach” (so no macro expansion takes place) where the tokens are treated in a peculiar way: character tokens are converted to uppercase or lowercase according to the `\uccode` and `\lccode` arrays, whereas any other token is left unchanged. Note that category codes are *not* changed.

Then the token list so obtained is sent back to the “mouth” where macro expansion can take place as usual.

Since the `\uccode` of the digits is 0, they're unchanged by `\uppercase`. Thus the code

```
\uppercase{\romannumeral1986}
```

is just an inefficient way to obtain the same result as

```
\romannumeral1986
```

So, how to obtain “MCMLXXXVI” from 1986? The ⟨filler⟩ is the answer, once you know that, when TeX is looking for the `{` that encloses a ⟨balanced text⟩, it performs expansion until finding some token that doesn't qualify as a space token, as `\relax` or as `{`. Space tokens and `\relax` tokens are ignored, though and the lookup for `{` starts again. In case TeX doesn't eventually find `{`, an error is raised.

This explains why

```
\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral1986}
```

actually produces the tokens `MCMLXXXVI` (all of category code 12). Indeed, `\expandafter` is expanded in the process of finding a `{` and discarding the ⟨filler⟩ and its expansion, according to the rules, is empty after having triggered the token following the next one, in this case `\romannumeral`. Thus, when the process actually finds `{`, the ⟨balanced text⟩ has already become

```
mcmlxxxvi
```

and so the processing in the stomach will send back the token list

```
MCMLXXXVI
```

which will be processed normally.

Actually the answer to exercise 7.9 should be

```
\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\year}
```

but it's just a detail.

**Exercise.** Explain what

```
\uppercase\ifodd\day\expandafter\expandafter\fi{\romannumeral\year}
```

produces and why two `\expandafter` tokens are used.

Comment: Thanks. 1. What is the meaning of **according to the rules, is empty after having triggered the token following the next one, in this case `\romannumeral`**? 2. For the exercise, my understanding is (parenthese represent sequence only ): `\uppercase\ifodd\day\expandafter\expandafter\fi{\romannumeral\year}` → `\uppercase\ifodd\day(\expandafter\expandafter\fi{\romannumeral\year})` . Then?  I don't know what `\expandafer\expandafer` will do. This is the first time I see two consecutive `\expandafter`.

Comment: @Y.zeng Go on reading the book and you'll understand.

Comment: Okay. I will return back here in the future.